# Is there any evidence of differences in e-commerce product quality perception around the world?

Tags: usability, e-commerce, product

Dealing with **fashion e-commerce** everyday, with a special focus on the Italian market, I’ve noticed each brand of our group (with its specific target) involves a different engagement concerning **quality, textile and manufacturing**. I also suppose it relates to a cultural factor. 
Apart from **a/b tests, recordings, heatmaps** I can produce on countries we are already reaching, is there any research concerning this topic, providing a sort of overview on how the aspects, mentioned above, appeal customers while browsing? Is there any evidence of the cultural differences I am presuming? 
I’ve recently held a **research** on how product pages differ around the countries our websites touch. But I do not feel this completely satisfies my new point. I’ve observed Asia asks for very long and dense pages, full of information. Actually, the websites we are serving them are not following these standards (they are a simple translation of their European versions) so I cannot collect any data concerning whether specific contents are attracting attention or not. 
Any suggestion is very welcome! 
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

This article suggests that perceived quality is a variable in how consumers treat eCommerce in different countries. Unfortunately, it's behind a paywall. :

[Global Differences in Online Shopping Behavior: Understanding Factors Leading to Trust](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07421222.2016.1267531)

> The impact of treatments and of vendor reputation on consumers’ trust
>   varied across countries in ways that we did not expect. In mature
>   online markets like the United States, online shopping appears to be
>   treated as just another form of shopping. In China, if an online
>   vendor can establish a reputation for quality, consumers appear to
>   treat those merchants much as Americans do their own favorite online
>   vendors, despite problems with Chinese shopping more generally.

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting question, and I imagine that these differences are in fact due to specific (yet vague) cultural factors from country to country. In my experience, some of these differences can be quite counterintuitive, and may change from product to product, brand to brand, even within the same country.

For this reason I would always recommend conducting original research wherever possible. You could start by creating a list of assumptions and hypotheses about what users are looking for in a particular country. These should be falsifiable - e.g. 'Users in Italy are much more interested in the quality of fabric than other markets.'

Then, run some simple surveys on those sites to validate or invalidate your assumptions. Multiple choice is usually best due to its simplicity - e.g. 'Choose the information that is most important to you when buying clothes online.'

Running the same survey on different sites should hopefully provide you with the insight you need. If surveys are not possible for whatever reason, you could try using sites like Statista to find some research data that relates to your issue.

https://www.statista.com/study/40989/apparel-market-in-italy/

Hope this helps!